# Get current keyboard language name in background

Tags: c#, winforms, language-detection

I'm trying to get current keyboard language name in background. I used `InputLanguage.CurrentInputLanguage.Culture.Name` but I understood that this code doesn't work when application isn't focused. I mean it can't detect language changes when app isn't focused and it always returns the last focused language.

So what can I do to detect current language in background? I'm using windows forms for my application.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to this answer to achieve what you want.

[Detect current keyboard language/layout name in multi-language computer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27747405/609731)

`Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.TwoLetterISOLanguageName` in the namespace `System.Threading`

Comment: Doesn't work! My keyboard has two languages, 'fa' and 'en'. I tried this code in a message box and it always shows me 'fa' with both languages.