# How to use c-cedilla key ProcessCmdKey shortcuts in c#

Tags: c#, keyboard-shortcuts

I want to create a shortcut that will perform a task when the letter "Ç" is pressed in my application. But there is no defined "Ç" key. How can I do this?
Example:

```
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
{
    switch (keyData)
    {
         case Keys.Alt | Keys.D1:
             // Number 1
             return true;
         case Keys.Alt | Keys.D2:
             // Number 2
             return true;
         case Keys.Ç:
             // There is no defined "Ç" (c-cedilla) key.
             return true;
        default:
            return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Press that key as see what Key Code + ModifierKeys it maps to

Comment: @jimi - I don't know how to use it. I searched a little bit, it is used with keys like Ctrl and Shift. I think I don't type "Ç" with keys like Ctrl and Shift.

Comment: You need to use virtual key codes here, [2nd column](https://kbdlayout.info/how/%C3%A7).  Note how that makes a terrible choice for a shortcut key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand from **Hans Passant**'s comment, the key assignment changes according to the keyboard combination. So I came up with this solution. Firstly specify the keyboard, then assign shortcut the appropriate OEM key. I know, it's very casuistic and software logic doesn't like casuistic things. But it's better than no solution. The best way I think, assign a shortcut to a standard letter, for example `C`.

```
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
{
    switch (keyData)
    {
        case Keys.Alt | Keys.D1:
        // Number 2
        case Keys.Alt | Keys.D2:
            // Number 1
            return true;
        // For Turkish Q
        default:
        {
            // For Turkish Q
            if (GetLayoutCode() == "0000041F" && keyData is Keys.Oem5)
            {
                // C-cedilla key.
                return true;
            }
            // For Spanish
            if (GetLayoutCode() == "0000040A" && keyData is Keys.Oem2)
            {
                // C-cedilla key.
                return true;
            }
            return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
        }
    }
}

private const int KL_NAMELENGTH = 9;
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern long GetKeyboardLayoutName(StringBuilder pwszKLID);
//each keyboard layout is defined in Windows as a hex code
public static string GetLayoutCode()
{
    var name = new StringBuilder(KL_NAMELENGTH);
    GetKeyboardLayoutName(name);

    return name.ToString();
}
```

[See](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27747176/detect-current-keyboard-language-layout-name-in-multi-language-computer) this topic about keyboard detection.